# How to run flutter on chrome using visual code editor

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

How to run flutter app on chrome.
I have installed flutter kit and also run
flutter channel beta 
flutter upgrade 
and also install extension on visual studio code.

Comment: do you have flutter version `1.12`? if so, follow https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just like with `flutter mobile` create `flutter launch` configuration, but add the following line: "args": [ "-d", "chrome" ]

```
{
  // launch.json
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Flutter for web",
      "type": "dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "lib/main.dart",
      "args": [
        "-d",
        "chrome"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's weird, `flutter run -d chrome` works fine for me but with this launch config, chrome cannot reach the site :(

Answer (score 12):

You can write on terminal:

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Comment: How do you run the widget selector here then?

Comment: we can use widget selector from vscode itself ,I think its not a problem

Answer (score 1):

@Spatz is correct but I also had right below his answer configuration

```
{
            "name": "new_app",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "new_app (profile mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        },
```

I had to delete these from launch.json for VSCode to launch the app in debug mode (able to step through) in Chrome.
Otherwise pushing F5 would start the debug mode but on my device.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple if you've installed chrome in your system..
for running in debug mode, run this command in terminal

**`flutter run -d chrome`**

For running in release mode

**`flutter run -d chrome --release`**